# Python interactive mode: calling next without using return value does not advance iterator

Tags: python-3.x, interactive-mode

If I execute,

```
a = iter([1,2,3])                                                      
for x in a: 
    print(x) 
    if x==1: 
        z=next(a)
```

I get

```
1
3
```

which I expect, since the call to `next` advances the iterator and skips the `2`.

**However in interactive mode** (command line), if I remove the `z=` assignment, and only call `next`, it behaves very differently.

```
>>> a = iter([1,2,3])                                                      
>>> for x in a: 
...    print(x) 
...    if x==1: 
...        next(a)
```

gives me

```
1
2
3
```

I'm using Python 3.8.8 in Windows 64 bits. Is this expected? It only happens in interactive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreter echoing back the return value of `next()` in addition to `x` being printed each iteration.

```
>>> a = iter([1,2,3])                                                      
>>> for x in a: 
...    print(x) 
...    if x==1: 
...        next(a)
```

So 1 and 3 is the output of `print(x)`, 2 the return value from `next()`. If you assign the output of `z=next()` things work as expected `1,3` because your z isn't returning or printing. Assigning the result of "next(a)" to a variable inhibits the printing of its' result so that just the alternate values that the "x" loop variable are printed

Comment: Of course! I feel so silly haha! Thank you!!